# Composer autoloader file for connecting to AWS DocumentDB

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, composer-php

I'm moving from a local MongoDB to AWS.

I'm trying to connect to an existing AWS DocumentDB using a php script.   Amazon provides a 'code demonstration' of connection to the DocumentDB here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html

The specific code is this:

```
<?php
//Include Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$SSL_DIR = "/home/ubuntu";
$SSL_FILE = "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem";

//Specify the Amazon DocumentDB cert
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "cafile" => $SSL_DIR . "/" . $SSL_FILE,
    ))
);

//Create a MongoDB client and open connection to Amazon DocumentDB
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://<sample-user>:<password>@sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017", array("ssl" => true), array("context" => $ctx));

//Specify the database and collection to be used
$col = $client->sample-database->sample-collection;

//Insert a single document
$result = $col->insertOne( [ 'hello' => 'Amazon DocumentDB'] );

//Find the document that was previously written
$result = $col->findOne(array('hello' => 'Amazon DocumentDB'));

//Print the result to the screen
print_r($result);
?>
```

When I navigate to this file with a web browser, I get no response.

If I drop in an echo before the 'require' I get the echo back.  An echo after that line, I do not.

I don't know what composer is doing, how to get it, or how I'd include it in this php script.

Note, when I run it 'locally' by running `php testConnect.php` on the linux server I get a `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found...` on the `$client = new MongoDB\Client...` line...

Comment: Is the box running this PHP script sitting outside the VPC?

Comment: Please share more details. A completely blank page is a good hint to experiment with the error reporting levels, and to search for the server's error log